# $n^\text{th}$ integral of $\operatorname{li}(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\newcommand{\li}{\operatorname{li}}\newcommand{\Ei}{\operatorname{Ei}}$The $n^\text{th}$ order integrals (without constants) of the log integral $\li(x)$ show an obvious pattern and can most definitely be generalized.
\begin{align}
& \li(x) \\[10pt]
& -\Ei(2\ln(x))+x\li(x) \\[10pt]
& \frac{1}{2}(-2x\Ei(2\ln(x))+\Ei(3\ln(x))+x^2\li(x)) \\[10pt]
& \frac{1}{6}(-3x^2\Ei(2\ln(x))+3x\Ei(3\ln(x))-\Ei(4\ln(x))+x^3\li(x)) \\[10pt]
& \frac{1}{24}(-4x^3\Ei(2\ln(x))+6x^2\Ei(3\ln(x))-4x\Ei(4\ln(x))+\Ei(5\ln(x))+x^4\li(x))
\end{align}

What would the general form be for an abritrary $n^\text{th}$ integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by OP's original answer, I explored why the result is the way it is. First, by reverse-engineering and then by forward derivation.

We want to express this in the form $\frac{1}{n!}(x-T)^n \operatorname{li}(x)$ where $T$ is an operator with the property

$$T\operatorname{li}(x^n)=\operatorname{li}(x^{n+1}).$$

We know that
$$\int_0^x \frac{t^n{\,\rm d}t}{\ln t}\overset{u=t^{n+1}}{=}\int_0^{x^{n+1}}\frac{du}{\ln u}=\operatorname{li}(x^{n+1})$$
so to transform $\operatorname{li}(x)$ into $\operatorname{li}(x^{n+1})$ you must differentiate, multiply by $x^n$, and integrate again. Therefore

$$T^n=\int x^n \partial$$
and because $\partial\int = 1$, we have $T^n T^m = T^{n+m}$ and $T^0=1$ as it should be. Of course, $\int$ is now an operator that works on everything to the right.

---

Now we go forward cleanly.

Your claim is now

$$\underbrace{\int\int\cdots\int}_n \operatorname{li}(x) = \frac{1}{n!}(x-\int x \partial)^n \operatorname{li}(x)$$

First, observe that the derivative of a product $\partial (x f(x))=f(x)+x \partial f(x)$ can be written in the operator form as

$$\partial x = x \partial + 1$$

or, as a commutator
$$\partial x - x\partial = 1$$
Which is just saying that order of differentiation and multiplication is important - this exact commutator leads to Heisenberg's uncertainty principle.

Now integrate the commutator to get

$$\int = x - \int x \partial$$

This is the essence of integration by parts. At this point it's useful to verify that $x$ and $\int x \partial $ actually commute, so that order of multiplication in binomial formula doesn't matter.

So now we have

$$\left(\int\right)^n = (x-\int x \partial )^n = (x-T)^n$$

The only thing to recall is that $\int$ is now an operator that always integrates all the way to the $x$, no matter how many times you apply it, while the multiple integral is actually $\ldots\int_0^{x}dt\int_0^{t} f(t')dt'$. So, in $(t,t')$ space, the double integral integrates over a triangle, while $\left(\int\right)^2$ integrates over a square. In multiple dimensions, this goes over all permutations of order of integration, so you get $n!$-times the value (see [time-ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-ordering#Time_ordering)). You are left with a completely general formula

$$\int_0^x\ldots\int_0^{t''}\int_0^{t'} f(t)dt\,dt'\,\cdots\,dt'' =\frac{1}{n!}\left(\int\right)^n f=\frac{1}{n!}\left(x-\int x \partial\right)^n f$$

This is true for any $f$ and is a general partial integration formula for multiple integration. In our particular case, we are lucky, that we actually don't have to integrate anything once we see the rule
$$ T\operatorname{li}(x^n)=\operatorname{li}(x^{n+1}).$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\li}{\operatorname{li}}\newcommand{\Ei}{\operatorname{Ei}}$
Well I've finally figured it out.

The $n^\text{th}$ integral of $\li(x)$ is equal to:

$$\frac{1}{n!}\sum^n_{k=0}(-1)^k{{n\choose k}}x^{n-k}\Ei((k+1)\ln(x))$$

$$=\frac{1}{n!}\sum^n_{k=0}(-1)^k{{n\choose k}}x^{n-k}\li(x^{k+1})$$

or
$$\sum^n_{k=0}(-1)^k\frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!k!}\li(x^{k+1})$$

Comment: This is a very pleasing solution, one of those expressions which follow rules from a different part of math that shouldn't apply, but they do (see umbral calculus). In this case, your solution is

$\frac{1}{n!}(x-y)^n$ with $y^k\mapsto li(x^{k+1})$.